# Centre a hexagon shape within a bootstrap column. Text-centre and margin: 0 auto; doesn't seems to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to centre the hexagon within the column. I've tried text-center and margin: 0 auto; as well. It is not getting centred. What I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to achieve this using bootstrap row and column.

```css
.hexa {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hex1 {
  float: left;
  border-right: 50px solid #2c0362;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}

.hex2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #2c0362;
}

.hex3 {
  float: left;
  border-left: 50px solid #2c0362;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}

.hex-text {
  font-size: 62px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 hexa text-center">
    <div class="hex1"></div>
    <div class="hex2">
      <p class="hex-text">Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hex3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` to `.hexa` and wrap it into `col-lg-6`,

if you are using `text-align:center`, child element must be `inline` or `inline-block`.

```css
.hexa {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hex1 {
  float: left;
  border-right: 50px solid #2c0362;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}

.hex2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #2c0362;
}

.hex3 {
  float: left;
  border-left: 50px solid #2c0362;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}

.hex-text {
  font-size: 62px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class=container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
      <div class=hexa>
        <div class="hex1"></div>
        <div class="hex2">
          <p class="hex-text">Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hex3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change. Add `display:table;` to `.hexa`.

It will center the element

```css
.hexa{
 margin: 0 auto;
  display:table;
}

.hex1{
 float: left;
 border-right: 50px solid #2c0362;
 border-top: 100px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}

.hex2{
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #2c0362;
}

.hex3{
 float: left;
 border-left: 50px solid #2c0362;
 border-top: 100px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}

.hex-text{
 font-size:62px;
 color:#fff;
 line-height:3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 hexa text-center">
    <div class="hex1"></div>
    <div class="hex2"><p class="hex-text">Text</p></div>
    <div class="hex3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see the desired output on your answer. But, even though I copy pasted your code It doesn't centre things on my page.